Header and Footer templates i created are not visible on single product pages
Im rebuilding a website that was previously created using wpbakery and an outdated theme, using elementor pro, in a staging environment.
i built almost everything in the theme builder, such as header, footer, different sections, etc.
i just finished creating the single product page and noticed both the header and footer are gone on that specific page!
they are visible everywhere else, but not on single product pages...
anyone has a solution for this problem?
i created another staging environment and i didnt have the same issue.
but i have already re-created the whole website, and im looking for a better solution that doesnt require me to do everything all over again, as the deadline is in a week...
